# Wave equation for a static fluid that does not flow

Tags: waves, black-holes

From the fluid dynamics, applying a linear approximation, I arrived at the following master sound-wave equation:

\begin{equation}
\partial_t \left( - c_S^{-2} \rho_0\left( \partial_t \psi_1 + \mathbf{v}_0 \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \psi_1\right) \right)    +  \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \left( - c_S^{-2} \rho_0 \mathbf{v}_0 \left( \partial_t \psi_1 + \mathbf{v}_0 \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla} \psi_1\right)  + \rho_0 \boldsymbol{\nabla} \psi_1\right)  = 0
\end{equation}

I have to assume a static background and it does not flow to reach the famous wave equation:

\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2 \psi_1 = c^2 \nabla^2 \psi_1
\end{equation}

What tricks or what mathematical tools do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard wave equation only applies to stationary background flows. There are various ways to write the equation for non-zero background flows, and your general case is probably one of them.  For some of these you can look at our old paper: arXiv:cond-mat/0106255 and the references it cites.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not solve it. The second term I think is easy, static  and after the chain rule  and using properties of nabla I get it.

The first term I do not know how it is. Should we use the Bernouilli equation and the barotropic condition?

How can I write math symbols here, at comments?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "solve"?  If you set ${\bf v}_0=0$ your equation reduces immediately to  the standard sound wave equation.